# How do I list all the roles to assign them in the registration form?

Tags: users, 9

I'm trying to alter the user registration form by adding a custom field which lists all the available roles in the site.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Since this is a question about code, we need to see the code you wrote so far. If you are asking the question before to implement it, you are asking the question too early. It's also not clear why you would need a custom field with all the roles, when they are always accessible from code.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an entity reference field to the user, referencing entities of type User Role. You can do this by enabling the Field UI module, and navigating to Admin -> Configuration -> People -> Account Settings -> Manage Fields (tab).